# Yet another 'Non-exhaustive patterns in function'

Tags: haskell

Begginer Haskell Question.
Actually I found very similiar question [Haskell error: "non-exhaustive patterns"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615031/haskell-error-non-exhaustive-patterns)

Interactive shell:

```
Prelude> merge [] [] = []
Prelude> merge (x:xs) [] = x:xs
Prelude> merge [] (y:ys) = y:ys
Prelude> -- merge (x:xs) (y:ys)

Prelude> merge [][]
Exception
Prelude> merge [0][]
Exception: <interactive>:3:1-22: Non-exhaustive patterns in function merge

Prelude> merger [][0]
OK
```

In fact exceptions exist also in non-interactive mode

```
main = do
   print (merge [1,2,3] [])
   print (merge [] [1,2,3])
   print (merge [] [])


merge :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge (x:xs) [] = x:xs
merge [] (y:ys) = y:ys
merge [][] = []
```

However it depends on order of particulas special cases of merge where error appears. 
I dont't really know why this happens. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two separate issues here.

<strike>You couldn't possibly have defined `merge` that way in GHCi.</strike> (Thanks for the correction, Alec!)

The first issue, which only happens in the interactive session, is that you are defining *three* separate functions called `merge`, each of which *shadows* the previous one. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26054046/46571) for someone who had a very similar problem to yours.

To enter a single multiline definition, you must use `:{` and `:}`:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| merge [] [] = []
Prelude| merge (x:xs) [] = x:xs
Prelude| merge [] (y:ys) = y:ys
Prelude| -- merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
Prelude| :}
Prelude>
```

However, in general, entering multiline definitions into GHCi is rather unpleasant, so you are better off storing your definitions into a normal `.hs` file and then loading this file into GHCi.

---

The second issue, which happens both in the interactive session and in the non-interactive program, is that your definition of `merge` isn't exhaustive: the case when both list arguments are nonempty isn't handled. Note that:

- If either list argument is empty, `merge` must return the other list.
- If both lists are nonempty, `merge` must extract the smallest head element (in either list), and then recursively merge the rest.

Thus, the correct definition of `merge` is:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| merge xs [] = xs
Prelude| merge [] ys = ys
Prelude| merge xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys)
Prelude|   | x <= y    = x : merge xs yys
Prelude|   | otherwise = y : merge xxs ys
Prelude| :}
Prelude> merge [1,3..9] [2,4..10]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Prelude>
```

Or, non-interactively:

```
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge xxs@(x:xs) yys@(y:ys)
  | x <= y    = x : merge xs yys
  | otherwise = y : merge xxs ys
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the newest version of GHC does let you omit the `let`, so each line overshadows the previous one

Comment: @Alec: TIL. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you not only corrected the syntax errors, but also corrected the code. OPs function still throws an error when defined in a file because there is no `merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = .. ` case

Comment: @user2407038: Right. Actually, I originally only intended to fix the problem with the interactive session, but then I couldn't help myself and wrote the correct version of `merge` en passant.